# Remove element in a XML file with Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm a newbie with Python and I'd like to remove the element openingHours and the child elements from the XML.

I have this input

```
<Root>
   <stations>
      <station id= "1">
          <name>whatever</name>
          <openingHours>
               <openingHour>
                    <entrance>main</entrance>
                       <timeInterval>
                         <from>05:30</from>
                         <to>21:30</to>
                       </timeInterval>
                <openingHour/>
          <openingHours>
      <station/>
      <station id= "2">
          <name>foo</name>
          <openingHours>
               <openingHour>
                    <entrance>main</entrance>
                       <timeInterval>
                         <from>06:30</from>
                         <to>21:30</to>
                       </timeInterval>
                <openingHour/>
          <openingHours>
       <station/>
   <stations/>
  <Root/>
```

I'd like this output

```
  <Root>
   <stations>
      <station id= "1">
          <name>whatever</name>
      <station/>
      <station id= "2">
          <name>foo</name>
      <station/>
   <stations/>
  <Root/>
```

So far I've tried this from another thread [How to remove elements from XML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593204/how-to-remove-elements-from-xml-using-python)

```
from lxml import etree

doc=etree.parse('stations.xml')
for elem in doc.xpath('//*[attribute::openingHour]'):
   parent = elem.getparent()
   parent.remove(elem)
print(etree.tostring(doc))
```

However, It doesn't seem to be working.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code for a spin but at first Python couldn't agree with the way you composed your XML, wanting the `/` in the closing tag to be at the beginning (like `</...>`) instead of at the end (`<.../>`).

That aside, the reason your code isn't working is because the `xpath` expression is looking for the **attribute** `openingHour` while in reality you want to look for **elements** called `openingHours`. I got it to work by changing the expression to `//openingHours`. Making the entire code:

```
from lxml import etree

doc=etree.parse('stations.xml')
for elem in doc.xpath('//openingHours'):
    parent = elem.getparent()
    parent.remove(elem)
print(etree.tostring(doc))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the tags `<openingHours>` and not some attribute with name `openingHour`:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('stations.xml')
for elem in doc.findall('.//openingHours'):
    parent = elem.getparent()
    parent.remove(elem)
print(etree.tostring(doc))
```