# lxml tag removing - unexpected result using lxml remove

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a XML and need to remove a few types of tags. I used the iter method to check each element. I noticed if there is a nested element its child is also deleted. The following tag will not be deleted. For example as follows, the tag delete2 is a child of delete1 and both will be removed. The tag section can't be deleted for some reason. Is this a bug? Or did I miss something? Thanks.

```
# %%
from lxml import etree

# unexpected output when nested elements are deleted
xml_str = """
<spdoc>
  <commentary>
    <body>
      <delete1>
        <delete2>
        </delete2>
      </delete1>
      <section name="delete">
      </section>
    </body>
  </commentary>
</spdoc>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
for element in root.iter():
    is_remove = False
    if element.tag == "delete1":
        is_remove = True
    if element.tag == "delete2":
        is_remove = True
    if element.tag == "section" and element.attrib.get("name") == "delete":
        is_remove = True
    print(f"{element} {is_remove}")
    if is_remove:
        element.getparent().remove(element)

print(etree.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8").decode("utf-8"))
```

## the unexpected output is :

```
<Element spdoc at 0x103489680> False
<Element commentary at 0x103489640> False
<Element body at 0x1034b5540> False
<Element delete1 at 0x1037eb700> True
<Element delete2 at 0x1037eba40> True
<spdoc>
    <commentary>
        <body>
            <section name="delete">
            </section>
        </body>
    </commentary>
</spdoc>
```

Comment: see: [Python: Removing list element while iterating over list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022764/python-removing-list-element-while-iterating-over-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)  (When debugging you could notice that `section` is not tested)

Comment: @Luuk sorry, I can't see any connections between my question and the links you shared? The link you shared is about Python list. However, my question is about using lxml to remove specific tags which is a different one. Why is it labelled as a duplicated. I really can't understand.

Comment: You are looping through a list (`for element in root.iter():`) and removing items from that list (`element.getparent().remove(element)`).  The result is that your source list is getting shorter, which leads to unexpected results... (see previous link on how to solve that)

Comment: @luuk Thanks for your comments. I understand what you wanted to say. I also know if I use list(root.iter()), the problem will be gone. What I don't understand is the behaviour of the iter method. It's a depth-first search. The remove operation doesn't edit un-visted node in the tree. Why it can get unexpected output? lxml python project doesn't have github issues. I want to try luck in Stackoverflow to see if anyone has this specific issue or knows how to resolve it.

Comment: it's not a bug of lxml, others have noticed this behavior (of python) too, see (for example): https://stackoverflow.com/a/33765394/724039

Comment: @Luuk: The linked questions are about lists, but `for element in root.iter()` does not loop over a list. It processes successive items returned by an iterator. I don't think that the behaviour demonstrated in the question is a bug, but I agree with the OP that it has not been fully explained.

Comment: @mzjn: You are free to explain it better 